# Scala placeholder syntax for anonymous function

Tags: scala

I have a val numSeq of type Array

```
scala> val numSeq=Array(3.1415,2.71828,9.8)
numSeq: Array[Double] = Array(3.1415, 2.71828, 9.8)
```

and now want to take each element within `numSeq` casting to `Int` and print them out, using placeholder syntax. There is no doubt that the following fails:

```
scala> numSeq foreach (println (_.toInt))
<console>:13: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1: <error>) => x$1.toInt)
   numSeq foreach (println (_.toInt))
```

But what makes me surprised is the following statement makes sense:

```
scala> numSeq foreach (Console println _.toInt)
3
2
9
```

But why it's Ok, just a prefix `Console` added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because of the lexical scopes and how they're recognized by scalac:

- `_.toInt` is a function
- `println(_.toInt)`: you want to print a function, the input type is not resolved
- `Console.println(_.toInt)`: same, printing a function
- `Console println _.toInt` is actually identical to: `(x => Console println x.toInt)`

Comment: Thank you. But what about ```numSeq foreach (Console println (_.toInt))```, enclosing ```_.toInt``` with parentheses? I thought it made no difference but I get an error message:```error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1: <error>) => x$1.toInt)```.

Comment: A pair of parentheses opens a new lexical scope, so it's the same as `Console println (x => x.toInt)`.